# What's the meaning of the word 'just' in this phrase: "There's never a point where you just gonna know everything."?

Tags: adverbs

Sometimes I get confused about the usage of "just" and the meaning of that word.
For example, in this phrase:

> There's never a point where you *just* gonna know everything.

What's the meaning of "just" in this context?

Comment: Similar to *plainly* or *absolutely* here.

Comment: @Yosef I disagree. In this context, it means "simply". Can you give me example sentences where "just" can mean "plainly" or "absolutely"? I can't think of any

Answer (score -1):

In this case, *just* means:

(OLD) [2: simply](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/just_1)

"There's never going to be a point where you are simply going to know everything."

This is stating knowledge is a much more complex matter, where you gain knowledge bit by bit, rather than all at once.